# Reading values from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been trying to find a way to combine the lines into one:

```
R: Code

Datensatz_LR[29]
Datensatz_LR[48,]
Datensatz_LR[63,]
Datensatz_LR[100,]

Output:
> Datensatz_LR[29,]
          Word  
29 Dog      
> Datensatz_LR[48,]
   Word  
48  cat       
> Datensatz_LR[63,]
   Word  
63  land       
> Datensatz_LR[100,]
    Word  
100 shoe
```

Datensatz is the name of the file that I have imported into R. I can work with it just fine, but I want to have less code and thought that maybe I could write something like this

```
pseudocode:
Datensatz_LR[29,46,63,100]


desired output of the pseudocode:
    Datensatz_LR[29,48,63,100]
                  Word  
        29 Dog      
        48  cat       
        63  land       
        100 shoe
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Would there be a way to make a more elegant version of this ? 
I apologise for the simple question. I am still relatively new to R.

Comment: does `Datensatz_LR[c(29,48,63,100),]` do the trick?

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect ! Thank you very much !